# loading .so library with cffi

Tags: python, python-cffi

I have some C library I want to access in Python using CFFI. After building the library, I get the 2 files: `$HOME/libcint/include/cint.h` and `$HOME/libcint/lib/libcint.so`.

Now for the CFFI API mode I tried:

```py
from cffi import FFI
libcint_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/libcint')
ffibuilder = FFI()
ffibuilder.set_source('_libcint',
  r'#include <include/cint.h>',
  include_dirs = [libcint_dir],
  libraries = ['libcint'],
  library_dirs = [os.path.join(libcint_dir, 'lib')],
)
```

But it fails to find the `libcint.so` file:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcint
```

The path in `libcint_dir` is correct, because I don't get any error message about not finding the header file. Also I managed to successfully interface the library using the `ctypes` module, so the `libcint.so` itself should be fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

If I get this right, then there are 3 steps required here. (Please correct me, if I confused something here.)

1. compiling libcint yielding `libcint.so`
2. building the Python wrapper with CFFI
3. importing the module built in step 2 into the actual Python program

My issue here is about the second step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying `libraries = ['libcint']`, which means that the compiler will look for a file called `liblibcint.so`.  What you should write is thus `libraries = ['cint']`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably bitten by the issue of compilation-time versus runtime location of libraries.  The path you give to the library is only used at compilation time by GCC.  At runtime, it looks for a library with the correct name, but using the system-configured default paths, only.  So you need to tell the system where to find that library.  You can do one of:

- move the library to a standard place like `/usr/local/lib`;
- run with the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library`;
- if you want to hard-code the path inside the compiled module, you can use `extra_link_args=['-Wl,-rpath=' + path]` in the call to set_source().

This is all assuming Linux.  On a different platform, all three options are probably available too but the details differ...

Comment: But I am talking about compilation. The code above is supposed to create `_libcint.c` and `_libcint.o`. Or did I confuse something here?

Comment: Ah, maybe I am confused.  It could be that you need to say ``libraries = ['cint']`` instead of ``libcint``.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Seems weird that the header file has a different name. Could you maybe reformulate your answer accordingly?

Comment: Done in a different answer.